# Change active language icon+name by following HTML lang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Live- http://uposonghar.com/lang.html

My Code-

```
<nav role="custom-dropdown" id="nav_language" dir="ltr">
<input type="checkbox" id="button">
<label for="button" id="labelLang" onclick><img alt="English" title="English" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/en_US.png"> English</label>
<ul>
    <li><a hreflang="en" href="http://chitrchatr.com/en/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/en_US.png" title="English" alt="English" />&nbsp;English</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="de" href="http://chitrchatr.com/de/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/de_DE.png" title="Deutsch" alt="Deutsch" />&nbsp;Deutsch</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="ru" href="http://chitrchatr.com/ru/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/ru_RU.png" title="Русский" alt="Русский" />&nbsp;Русский</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="es" href="http://chitrchatr.com/es/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/es_ES.png" title="Español" alt="Español" />&nbsp;Español</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="zh" href="http://chitrchatr.com/zh/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/zh_CN.png" title="中文 (中国)" alt="中文 (中国)" />&nbsp;中文 (中国)</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="ar" href="http://chitrchatr.com/ar/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/ar.png" title="العربية" alt="العربية" />&nbsp;العربية</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="fr" href="http://chitrchatr.com/fr/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/fr_FR.png" title="Français" alt="Français" />&nbsp;Français</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="it" href="http://chitrchatr.com/it/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/it_IT.png" title="Italiano" alt="Italiano" />&nbsp;Italiano</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="in" href="http://chitrchatr.com/in/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/id_ID.png" title="Bahasa Indonesia" alt="Bahasa Indonesia" />&nbsp;Bahasa Indonesia</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="ko" href="http://chitrchatr.com/ko/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/ko_KR.png" title="한국어" alt="한국어" />&nbsp;한국어</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="th" href="http://chitrchatr.com/th/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/th.png" title="ไทย" alt="ไทย" />&nbsp;ไทย</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="tl" href="http://chitrchatr.com/tl/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/tl.png" title="Tagalog" alt="Tagalog" />&nbsp;Tagalog</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="hi" href="http://chitrchatr.com/hi/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/hi_IN.png" title="हिन्दी" alt="हिन्दी" />&nbsp;हिन्दी</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="ja" href="http://chitrchatr.com/ja/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/ja.png" title="日本語" alt="日本語" />&nbsp;日本語</a></li>
    <li><a hreflang="sv" href="http://chitrchatr.com/sv/"><img src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/sv_SE.png" title="Svenska" alt="Svenska" />&nbsp;Svenska</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to code it like when `<html lang="de-DE">` Then 
That-

```
<label for="button" id="labelLang" onclick><img alt="English" title="English" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/en_US.png"> English</label>
```

Will be-

```
<label for="button" id="labelLang" onclick><img alt="German" title="German" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/de-DE.png"> German</label>
```

Again when `<html lang="it-IT">` Then 
That-

```
<label for="button" id="labelLang" onclick><img alt="English" title="English" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/en_US.png"> English</label>
```

Will be-

```
<label for="button" id="labelLang" onclick><img alt="Italian" title="Italian" src="http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/it-IT.png"> Italian</label>
```

I know that is possible by JavaScript, i know how to get html lang value by JavaScript but don't know how to change Language name+icon by lang value.

Comment: What have you already tried for that?

Comment: I have  made a prototype ,Is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/e755M/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var langarr = ['en_US.png','de-DE.png','it-IT.png']; 
var lansrc = "http://chitrchatr.com/wp-content/plugins/polylang/flags/";
var labelLang = $('#labelLang');
```

- then You can just add it Dynamically : like

  ```
     labelLang.attr('src',lansrc+langarr[0]) //for en-US
     labelLang.attr('src',lansrc+langarr[1]) //for de-DE
     labelLang.attr('src',lansrc+langarr[2]) //for it-IT
  ```

Answer (score 1):

and then use js! :D
give the label an unique id.
after loading the page run a javascript function that access the element using

```
lbl = document.getElementById("idvalue")
lbl.setAttribute("alt","xxx")
```

I didn't tried the code there could be some errors. but it's a hint :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will set label's img values dynamically.

```
    var lang = document.documentElement.lang

    var sub;

    if ( lang.length == 5 && (lang.indexOf("-") != -1) )  {
        sub = lang.replace('-','_') + ".png"; 
    }
    else if (lang.length == 2) {
        sub = lang + ".png"; 
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    $("img[src]").each(function(){

        if ( $(this).parent("a") && $(this).attr('src').indexOf(sub) > 0) {

            var labels_img = $("label > img");

            $("label").html("");

            labels_img.attr('src', $(this).attr('src') );

            labels_img.attr('title', $(this).attr('title') );  

            labels_img.attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt') );

            $("label").html(labels_img);

            $("label").append( $(this).attr('title') );

<!-- uncomment below to see html -->
<!--        alert( $("label").parent().html()); -->

            return false;   
        }

    });
```

But like said before, I think too that it will be more practical and less work if you use id's in your tags.